# When default exporting a constant, how is it possible to reference a collection within the constant using the name of another value in the constant?

Tags: javascript

I'm working on some existing code that exports a collection of key/value pairs by using a spread operation in the default export of a service like this:

**keyValuePairs**

```
{
  key1: func1,
  key2: func2
}
```

**service.js**

```
const myConst = {
   //stuff here
};

export default {
  myConst,
  ...keyValuePairs,
};
```

**consumer.js**

```
import myConst from 'service.js';

// invoke delegate function by referencing its key in collection
myConst.key1
```

How am I able to reference `key1` in the consumer as `myConst.key1`, when `myConst` is the name of a constant that's included in the export?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
export default {
  myConst,
  ...keyValuePairs,
};
```

is simply equivalent (aside from there being no `someAnonymousThing` in the module's namespace) to

```
const someAnonymousThing = {
  myConst,
  ...keyValuePairs,
};
export default someAnonymousThing;
```

so it's not a special pattern of exporting at all; just a regular object being exported as the default object of that module.

If the `...` spread operator is new, then [see the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

Comment: No, that's not what happening here at all. It's just constructing an object of the shape `{"myConst": myConst, ...}` and exporting that. There is a single object exported with this syntax.

Comment: OK I figured out my confusion. It's because of name independence in exports. The default export is a constant, and when the default import is imported from the service, it's being imported (and therefore aliased) as `myConst`. That's confusing, as there's a constant within the service that's also called `myConst`, which isn't what's actually being referenced by `myConst` in the consumer.

Comment: Yes, as an importer you're at liberty of choosing any name you like for the default value. `import quadVentiPumpkinSpiceLatte from 'service.js';` and `console.log(quadVentiPumpkinSpiceLatte.key1)` will work fine too.